# Ambiguous grammar $S\to ABA$, $A\to aA|\varepsilon$, $B\to bB|\varepsilon$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, context-free-grammar

I need to show that: $$S \rightarrow ABA $$
$$A \rightarrow aA|\varepsilon$$
$$B \rightarrow bB|\varepsilon$$
is ambiguous and find an equivalent unambiguous grammar. I can't seem to see how this is ambiguous to begin with. Can someone explain how it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are (at least) two left derivations for $a$:

$S \to ABA \xrightarrow{A \to aA} aABA \xrightarrow{A \to \varepsilon} aBA  \xrightarrow{B \to \varepsilon} aA  \xrightarrow{A \to \varepsilon} a$

and

$S \to ABA \xrightarrow{A \to \varepsilon} BA \xrightarrow{B \to \varepsilon} A  \xrightarrow{A \to aA} aA  \xrightarrow{A \to \varepsilon} a$

Comment: Oh wow. I am blind. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It is ambiguous, because the string $a$ has more than one left derivation.

We have
$$S\to ABA\to aA\epsilon\epsilon = aA\to a\epsilon = a,$$
but also
$$S\to ABA\to \epsilon\epsilon aA = aA \to a\epsilon = a.$$

Comment: Ya I didn't catch on for that one. Thank you!